# How to retrieve previous action name from the current action in apache oozie?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Is there any EL function to get previous action name from current action in oozie workflow. 
If it is not possible with EL function how it is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to get the error message use wf:lastErrorNode()

```
<kill name="kill">
  <message>
    Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
  </message>
</kill>
```

Comment: that's is the case of error node. What if the previous action is succeeded ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use capture_output tags to navigate the node names in workflow. But this is  limited to java and shell actions.